# Creating Sankey Diagram using ggplot2, plotly and ggplotly

Tags: json, r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I want to create a sankey diagram using ggplot2 and plotly and call using ggplotly. I would require some good working examples with some crucial links.I have implemented one in plotly and this is the snap I achieved. Please help and thanks.

Editing the script:

```
library(googleVis)
datSK <- data.frame(From=c(rep("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6","r7")),              
To=c(rep(c("Blood Test", "Check Out", "Discuss Results","MRI SCAN",
                           "Registration","Triage and Assessment","XRay"))),
Weight=c(237,492,495,236,500,500,261))
Sankey <- gvisSankey(datSK, from="From", to="To", weight="Weight",
                 options=list(
                   sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },
                        node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },
                        label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))
plot(Sankey)
```

[image: Sankey]

Comment: Have you tried ... Google? You really need to provide more information, and  also make a first attempt, and let us know what did / did not work.

Comment: Thanks for replying, please see the edit, what I am also looking for is an onclick function which helps me to click on the lines and view the data.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma, kindly help me with this requirement in Sankey for which I need help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921885/error-with-sankey-chart-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 0):

This question is extremely old now and this answer wasn't around then, but the ggforce package now allows for sankey diagrams to be plotted in ggplot. There is currently no ggplotly support (and as such no interactablilty) but for simple sankeys it is now the best option I have found in that it works with the tidy data framework.

Comment: which ggforce function implements sankeys? I have found none in the reference. https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/index.html

Comment: They're called Parallel Sets in the package, you can see an example here https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/ . I've only ever used them once, but they seemed to work pretty much out the box assuming your data was in the right format.